# Required checks for PR do not run when workflows depend on other workflow files

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a `main` branch, a `dev` branch and feature branches.

I have three workflow files: `test` `build` and `deploy`

I want PRs to `main` to run all these workflows, but PRs to `dev` to just run the test workflow.

`build` should depend on `test` to succeed, and `deploy` should depend on `build`.

In `test.yml` I have:

```yaml
name: GameCI Tests in EditMode
on:
   pull_request:
      branches: [main, development]
```

Then in `build.yml` I have:

```yaml
name: GameCI Build
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [GameCI Tests in EditMode]
    branches: [main]
    types:
      - completed
```

and `deploy.yml`:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [GameCI Build]
    branches: [main]
    types:
      - completed
```

In `build` and `deploy` I then only run the workflows if the test workflow succeeded:

`if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}`

Now, in my repo I enabled branch protection for main and development, and require 'Checks' to pass. For the `dev` branch I require only the test check, for `main` I require all checks.

This works fine for the `dev` branch - it only runs the tester and then reports back the status, after which I can merge the branch.
The issue is that when I make a PR to main, the `test` workflow runs and completes, but the other checks never finish because they are always stuck on `expected`. So I can never complete the PR because the required checks come from a workflow that is never dispatched.

What am I doing wrong here?

I think the above should already provide a minimum example that is needed to reproduce the problems in my post, but for sake of completion I uploaded the contents of all my three workflow files [here](https://gist.github.com/kemmel-dev/29c0154284a9a9c47c465a3071513d14).

[image]

Comment: I believe you could use one workflow that would trigger for all PRs, but with conditions to run the jobs executing each operation (build, test and deploy), where those jobs would be [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) (as they are the same for each scenario).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with some solution. I went for relying on `workflow_call` instead.

I set up the reusable workflow using:

```yaml
name: Some reusable workflow
on:
  workflow_call
```

```yaml
name: Run pull request checks for main

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
    
jobs:
  testRunner:
    name: Test
    uses: ./.github/workflows/game-ci_test.yml

  builder:
    name: Build
    needs: testRunner
    uses: ./.github/workflows/game-ci_build.yml
```

Now I can add another workflow file and set it's own requirements for the steps I want to take place:

```yaml
name: Run pull request checks for development

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [development]
    
jobs:
  testRunner:
    name: Test
    uses: ./.github/workflows/game-ci_test.yml
```